# why are my javascript items being removed?

Tags: javascript

I created a var (outside of any methods) called memberList. It contains the .... items for a select field. I build it like this:

```
//build the option list, append
for (var i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; i++) {
    var obj = jsonarray[i];

    daySelect = document.getElementById('member');
    daySelect.options[daySelect.options.length] = new Option(obj.lastName + ', ' + obj.firstName, obj.memberId);
    console.log(obj.lastName + ', ' + obj.firstName, obj.memberId);

}

memberList = daySelect.options;
```

Then on my form I have the ability for folks to add more select boxes (more people, essentially). I then put this code together which creates the new select boxes just fine, but I can't seem to get the array to carry over. This method is called whenever someone wants to add a new row to the form.

```
var selectMember = document.createElement("select");
selectMember.style = "width:200px;";
selectMember.id = "member" + document.getElementsByName('member').length;
selectMember.name = "member";
selectMember.className = "form-control";
//selectMember.options = memberList;

console.log('memberlist-a: ' + memberList.length);
var cloneList = jQuery.extend({}, memberList);
console.log('memberlist-b: ' + memberList.length);

for (var i = 0; i < cloneList.length; i++) {
    var obj = cloneList[i];
    selectMember.options[selectMember.options.length] = obj; 
    console.log('memberlist-inloop: ' + memberList.length);
}

console.log('memberlist: ' + memberList.length);
```

My console logs show me:

- memberList-a : 184 rows
- memberList-b : 184 rows
- memberList-inloop: constantly decreasing to zero, one by one
- memberList: 0

My questions:

1) How is my iterating through a copy (and yeah, I've tried the deep copy) of array2 (clonelist) removing items from array1 (memberList)?

2) And regardless, why does iterating and adding items to an html select option make them vanish from an array?

Comment: Appending an element to another element automatically removes it from its current parent. Instead of `jQuery.extend` try `var cloneList = [...memberList].map(el => el.cloneNode(true));`.

Comment: I'd like to look into your problem, but it's missing some data, could you post a runnable example?